# Flutter align TextFormField and Ico

Tags: flutter

I try to vertically align a TextFormField and an icon within a row. The issue is that as long as the TextFormField does not have a 'helperText' or a 'maxLength' everything works correctly but if I add them I get the misalignment in the figure, how can I fix it?

[image]

```
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,15),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        //minLines: 1,
                        validator: ValidationBuilder().minLength(MINLENGHT, "TITLEVALIDATOR".tr).maxLength(MAXLENGHT).required().build(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if(value.length>=MINLENGHT && value.length<=MAXLENGHT){
                            inputKeywordValidate.value = true;
                          }else{
                            inputKeywordValidate.value = false;
                          }
                        },
                        maxLength: MAXLENGHT,
                        controller: controllerKeywords,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                          helperText: 'KEYWORDINPUTHELPERTEXT'.tr,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'KEYWORDINPUTTITLE'.tr,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                IgnorePointer(
                    ignoring: ! validation,
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 40,
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: color),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_rounded, color: color),
                      onPressed: () {
                        keywordList.add(controllerKeywords.text);
                        inputKeywordValidate.value = false;
                        controllerKeywords.clear();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
               
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try by wrapping the `IconButton` widget with a `SizedBox` widget to give it a fixed width.

```
SizedBox(
      width: 60, // adjust the width as needed
      child: IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: !validation,
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 40,
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: color),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_rounded, color: color),
          onPressed: () {
            keywordList.add(controllerKeywords.text);
            inputKeywordValidate.value = false;
            controllerKeywords.clear();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`. If you need more padding on IconButton,  use `padding`.

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Flexible(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
      child: TextFormField(
        minLines: 1,
        // validator: ValidationBuilder()
        //     .minLength(MINLENGHT, "TITLEVALIDATOR".tr)
        //     .maxLength(MAXLENGHT)
        //     .required()
        //     .build(),
        onChanged: (value) {},
        // maxLength: MAXLENGHT,
        // controller: controllerKeywords,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          helperText: 'KEYWORDINPUTHELPERTEXT',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          // labelText: 'KEYWORDINPUTTITLE',
        ),
      ),
    )),
    IgnorePointer(
      // ignoring: !validation,
      child: IconButton(
        // padding: , ///use it
        iconSize: 40,
        // style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: color),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.add_circle_rounded,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```